# How to send OSC message from Cactus Micro Rev 2 (with on-board ESP8266 ESP-3) via UDP

Tags: arduino, osc, esp8266

Does anyone here know how to send OSC messages via the ESP8266 module on Cactus Micro R2?

I will use two HR-C04 Ultrasonic sensors linked to Cactus Micro R2 and I need to send the data of these sensors wirelessly to Processing (on Mac). Assumed sending OSC message over UDP is the easiest way. I have tried existing arduino libraries **esp8266-OSC**(https://github.com/sandeepmistry/esp8266-OSC) and **esp8266WiFi** (https://github.com/sandeepmistry/esp8266-Arduino/tree/master/esp8266com/esp8266/libraries/ESP8266WiFi) but none of them worked for my Cactus Micro R2 (and the latter even has compile error in c). If anyone knows any other existing library (or have successful experience sending OSC messages from the module)?
Thanks in advance.

PS: I could connect to WiFi at baud rate 9600. All AT commands work.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about OSC, but have been working a bit with the Cactus Micro Rev2, so maybe I can help anyway.
The Cactus Micro has two controllers on it, an ATMEGA32U4, and an ESP8266, connected via the UART. The 32U4 is responsible for powering on the ESP.

The ESP can run a variety of different firmwares. You seem to still be using the default AT-command based firmware, which is actually a real pain to deal with. It is very easy to write code for the ESP itself, using the Arduino environment. In this way, you can program the ESP to connect to your wifi, make TCP connections to servers, etc, and simply relay information received over the UART from the 32U4.

An alternative is to program the ESP using the native SDK. A fairly usable example of this is the esp-link code base, which provides an ethernet to serial adapter running on the ESP, relaying whatever comes across the UART to the TCP socket. Although the esp-link firmware is able to program an attached microcontroller, this cannot be used to program the 32U4 on the Cactus Micro, unfortunately, because of how power is supplied to the ESP.

I hope this helps a little bit.